# Count occurrences of values

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, pivot-table, countif

I have a column of text values with repeated values. I want to create a new column of unique values (no repeats) and a column with the frequency of each of those values.

What's the easiest way to do that? Efficiency isn't much of a concern as it's under 10,000 rows.

Comment: Create a pivot table.

Comment: This has been asked many times before.

Comment: brettdj - Have any links to related topics? I didn't see any when I searched.

Comment: One of the discussions:
http://superuser.com/questions/49614/how-do-i-get-the-distinct-values-in-a-column-in-excel

Answer (score 23):

For the sake of an answer rather than comments, copy column (say A) to B (say) and for B only Data > Data Tools – Remove Duplicates then in C2 enter:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B2)
```

and copy down as required

OR (preferred option)

use a PivotTable as @Tim:

[image: SO13151320 example]

Comment: Clever and simple to do.

Comment: doesn't work -> "the formula you typed contains an error"